# Run code once worklight server is started (Not client startup)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, startup, init

we have been working with IBM Worklight for some time now and we have run in the following issue.

When our server starts we want it to run some initial code to fill and update our database with data. This is a process that runs once everyday. But in order to do this we need to be able to start a cron job or something simular.

We know how to use cron jobs and stuff like that. But what we have not managed is to have this cronjob to start once the work light server is started.

so to summarize my question:

How can we run code on the worklight server automaticly once the work light server has started?

```
private void code(){
     //Run this code once Worklight server is started
}
```

Some aditional information on 07-03-2014:

So i have tried the ServletContextListener but no success. Tried to print something in the logger so i could see if my Importer class is running.
here is what i used

Java file:

```
public class Importer implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
        logger.warning("running this shizzle :D");

    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

web.xml file added and placed back in the .war package:

```
<listener>  
    <listener-class>com.ibm.nl.wwdw.server.connections.Importer</listener-class>    
</listener>
```

console log:

> [2014-03-07 12:59:22]             Worklight Server started
>   successfully on localhost:8080 [2014-03-07 12:59:22]
>   Activating Worklight project: mobile-app... [2014-03-07 12:59:25]
>   FWLSE2001I: Detected more than one IP address. Using 192.168.75.3 as
>   the public IP address of the Worklight Server. You can set a different
>   IP address in worklight.properties. [2014-03-07 12:59:25] FWLSE3005I:
>   Application raw reports are disabled. [2014-03-07 12:59:25]
>   FWLST0010I: ====== Started server for project
>   mobile-app-project-customization; Worklight
>   version=5.0.5.20121130-0158 [2014-03-07 12:59:25]
>   Activation done.

Comment: What is the underlying server?  WAS liberty, full profile, or tomcat?  Do you need the startup code to be in JavaScript, or would Java work for you?

Comment: It runs on websphere as the underlaying server. 
i would like the code to run in java.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a java class that implements ServletContextListener..
It has a method called contextInitialized that is fired when the servlet container first fires up.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

You would have to add the context listener to the web.xml after its generated:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.yourcomp.project.ContextListenerClass
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: That is not a good idea, because every build in Worklight Studio will regenerate the web.xml (which lays inside the .war file). This can be done ONLY after generating the .war file and deploying it. It will be easy to forget this step in every future deployment of the .war file...

Comment: While not the best thing, I think it's the only viable one?

Comment: Does the startup code have to be in the Worklight project WAR?  Or could it simply be in its own WAR?  If the code can run in its own WAR, then that would eliminate the problem with web.xml getting regenerated for the Worklight project WAR.

Comment: It would be most easy for us if it is inside worklight. The code that runs on startup has a lot of API calls that it needs to do and we take advantage of it's own HTTP adapters

Comment: So i have tried the ServletContextListener but have nog succeeded sofar. I have added the code used to start the Servlet in my first post. but this didn't really seems to start anything

Comment: Yes the listener code is inside the web.xml. Opened the original. added those 3 lines and placed it back in the .war file